# Which open source erlang projects are using google protobuf?

Tags: serialization, erlang

I am working with erlang project which uses *google protobuf* via https://github.com/basho/erlang_protobuffs

After some time I've got not such good impresion about it (I've found usage of this technology in erlang very clumsy and inconvenient). But of course, I known that this is because I can not cook it properly.

Which open source erlang project are using *erlang_protobuffs*? I am interested in best (or at least sufficient) practices of its usage.

Comment: Looking at this for the first time, it is not clear to me that protobuf solves a problem Erlang has.

Comment: I am trying to use protobuf to implement network interaction with another (non-erlang) service. It just encodes DTO's to binary format to send messages via network. I'm not sure that I do it rigth way (actually this is because I wrote a lot of silly boilerplate code that maps DTO's to application-level records and vice-versa). So I just want to look how other people deals with it.

Comment: ASN.1, binary syntax, an Erlang interoperation library (especially used between C/C++/Java/Python and Erlang), JSON (or limited YAML, to get fancy), and trashier solutions like weak XML export. Packing binaries by hand in Erlang isn't that hard, so depending on what you are doing this might not be insane (but DTOs can be insane). If you are familiar with ASN.1, writing a definition and feeding it to a Java, C, etc. ASN.1 compiler and the Erlang asn1 lib works well -- but without knowing the situation, no telling what fits.

Comment: Useful remark, thanks. I think I should to rethink protobuf purposes and intentions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you mean http://github.com/basho/erlang_protobuffs library.

From major opensource projects I know only basho's riak using this library, although 
[Github code search](https://github.com/search?q=erlang_protobuffs%20in%3Arebar.config&type=Code) gives a lot of different projects.

Note, that this library is not only one, take a look at this [post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/erlang-programming/vS6FuTuZ82A/Unz2SOOJ5xkJ)

Comment: Whoa, thanks. I didn't even think about most obvious way - use github search *FACEPALM*